# Call a python function from a fortran file converted by f2py

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran, fortran77, f2py

I am converting a large bit of FORTRAN code into python and using certain functions as FORTRAN functions itself and using them as `.so` files by using f2py3.

In one of these modules I am calling a function that has been converted to python already. What possible changes should I make to be able to use that ?

Sample fortran code :

```
SUBROUTINE MONTEFE                                                
  IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
  IMPLICIT INTEGER*8 (I-N)                                         
  COMMON/INPT/NGAS,NSTEP,NANISO,EFINAL,ESTEP,AKT,ARY,TEMPC,TORR,IPEN
  COMMON/INPT1/NDVEC
  NELEC=0
  NEGION=0
  TLAST=0.0D0
  ST=0.0D0
  TDASH=0.0D0
  IF(IMIP.EQ.2) GO TO 1
  IF(IMIP.GT.2) THEN
  CALL CASRES(J11,IBADTOT,IBAD1)
  IF(IBAD1.EQ.1) THEN
    J1=J1-1
    GO TO 210
   ENDIF 
   ELSE IF(IMIP.EQ.1) THEN

    CALL CASREM(J11)
    EST1=ECAS(1)
    EST2=EST1
  ENDIF
  STOP                      
  RETURN                                                            
  END
```

`CASREM()` is a python function in a separate module

```
f2py3 -m Montefe -c Montefe.f
```

is what I used to get the `.so` file

Comment: You have a "GO TO 1" statement in your code but there is no line numbered 1.

Comment: @jmh I will correct that, however that doesn't affect my query really